# Haskell higher order function help needed

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

What is the problem with this code?

```
addNum :: Int->Int-> Int
addNum a b = a+b

divideby :: ( Int->Int -> Int ) -> Int  ->float
divideby  f  z  =  f /z
```

I want to take the `addNum` function as an input to `divideby` with a divisor and then output the answer. So the `divideby` function should act as a higher order function.

What is the problem with this code? It gives following error:

```
*** Expression     : f / z
*** Term           : f
*** Type           : Int -> Int -> Int
*** Does not match : Int
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means exactly what the error says. You have specified that the type of your function is

```
divideby :: ( Int->Int -> Int ) -> Int  ->float
```

That means, the first argument must be a function, with the type `Int->Int -> Int`, and the second input must be an `Int`, and then it will produce a `float`. Naturally, Haskell does not know how to divide a function by an Int, which is what you are telling it to do with the expression `f / z`.

---

In response to the comment: no. That is not a higher-order function, but it is close. Take a look:

```
addNum :: Int -> Int -> Int
addNum a b = a + b

divideBy :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
divideBy a b c = (addNum a b) `div` c
```

`divideBy` is a function that takes 3 `Int`s as input, and produces an `Int`. Since its inputs are merely `Int`, it is *not* a higher-order function. However, you could abstract the use of `addNum` into an input, thus making it a higher-order function. `addNum` has type `(Int -> Int -> Int)`, so, in addition to the inputs we have already, we will make that the type of our first input

```
divideBy :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
divideBy f a b c = (f a b) `div` c
```

*This* is a higher-order function, that also compiles correctly and has meaning. :) You can pass `addNum` as an input to this function.

```
ghci> divideBy addNum 2 4 6 -- (2 + 4) / 6
1
```

Comment: is this correct? is this a higher order function? {addNum :: Int->Int-> Int
addNum a b = a+b

divideby :: Int -> Int -> Int-> a
divideby a b c =  (addNum a b) `div` c}

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between `float` and `Float`... the former is a type variable, the latter is a concrete type (for which you almost definitely want `Double` instead).

This is in connection with Dan Burton's answer.

Answer (score 1):

> i want to take addNum function as a Input in to divideby function with divide factor and then output the answer.

First of all, `divideby` function is a function, that takes 2 number `f` and `z` and returns `f/z`. As Dan Burton said, if `divideby` function return a division of two `Int` values, it cannot get function `Int -> Int -> Int` as argument.

So it could looks like that:

```
divideby :: Int -> Int -> Float
divideby  f z  =  (fromIntegral f) / (fromIntegral z)
```

If you want to construct some function as superposition of `divideby` and `addNum`, like taking `addNum`'s result as first argument of `divideby`, you can do it like that:

```
newFunction :: Int -> Int -> Float
newFunction a b = divideby (addNum a b) b
```

Which is actually equals to `(a+b)/b`.